# Generic Type Inference in C#

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Let's say there are these generic types in C#:

```
class Entity<KeyType>
{
    public KeyType Id { get; private set; }
    ...
}

interface IRepository<KeyType, EntityType> where EntityType : Entity<KeyType>
{
    EntityType Get(KeyType id);
    ...
}
```

and these concrete types:

```
class Person : Entity<int> { ... }

interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<int, Person> { ... }
```

Now the definition of `PersonRepository` is redundant: the fact that the `KeyType` of `Person` is `int` is stated explicitly, although it can be deduced from the fact that `Person` is a subtype of `Entity<int>`.

It would be nice to be able to define `IPersonRepository` like this:

```
interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person> { ... }
```

and let the compiler figure out that the `KeyType` is `int`. Is it possible?

Comment: How should it be able to know the `KeyType`? Can you show the full syntax of what you expect? Your last interface definition looks not complete.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The compiler is not "clever" enough. I won't make it an answer though because "I can't think of any way you can do it" is not proof enough you can't.

Comment: I'm presuming the last line of code should be `interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person> { ... }`

Comment: I expect something like this: `interface IRepository<EntityType> where EntityType : Entity<KeyType> { ... }`. However the compiler says that `KeyType` is not found.

Comment: Now try writing the `Get` method in your `IPersonRepository` without having to hard code `int` there and you'll realise there's not a great deal of benefit to this proposal.

Comment: Of course KeyType is not found: you did not declare it in the definition of your interface.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There are potential benefits in code *referencing* the interface, not just *implementing* it.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman question is quite clear
@proskor wants to be able to write something like
`interface IRepository<EntityType<KeyType>>
{
    EntityType Get(KeyType id);
}`

to extract type from another type.

I think it is impossible; there are some issues with generics - e.g. I cannot use +,- operators with variables of generic type. So, I think, that would be great to get hist feature implemented, but it doesn't seem to happen soon.

Comment: @Dennis_E I know. That's the point. However IMHO it is not really necessary to declare it. At least I should not be forced to repeat it in the definition of `IPersonRepository`.

Comment: I agree with Falanwe, the compiler is not clever enough. It does not look into the definition of `Person` to figure out it's actually another generic type, and then extract *that* generic component out. If it's able to do that, then it must be a very slow compiler! And it gets worse if you have cyclic inference...

Comment: @ViktorArsanov: The correct interface declaration was added after my comment. OP doesn't explain how he thinks the type should be inferred and what the usage is. That will make a lot clear as Damian explained.

Comment: I wonder why people are trying to make everything generic. Generic repositories for generic entities with generic key types... Abstractions of abstractions of abstractions make life very complicated. I think reuse is *highly* overrated in our trade.

Comment: @DennisTraub I totally agree. However this is a question out of curiosity; sometimes it can be useful to know the limits of the technology you are using.

Comment: @proskor You would not be repeating it; KeyType in IRepository is not the same KeyType in Entity. If you want to use a Generic Type, you will need to declare it.

Comment: Fair warning: The repository pattern will eat your soul. Just use your context. Parametricity in the form of generics however is amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we want to declare

```
interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person> { }
```

That would require that there is a generic interface with one type parameter `IRepository<EntityType>`.

```
interface IRepository<EntityType> where EntityType : Entity<KeyType>
{
    EntityType Get(KeyType id);
}
```

At the end of the first line, you refer to a thing called `KeyType`, which hasn't been declared nor defined. There is no type called "KeyType".

This would work though:

```
interface IRepository<EntityType> where EntityType : Entity<int>
{
    EntityType Get(int id);
}
```

Or this:

```
interface IRepository<EntityType> where EntityType : Entity<string>
{
    EntityType Get(string id);
}
```

But you cannot have both conflicting definitions at the same time of course. Obviously, you're not happy with that, because you want to be able to define your IRpository interface in such a way that it works with other key types as well.

Well, you can, if you make it generic in the key type:

```
interface IRepository<KeyType, EntityType> where EntityType : Entity<KeyType>
{
    EntityType Get(KeyType id);
}
```

There is an alternative approach:

```
interface IRepository<KeyType>
{
    EntityType<KeyType> Get(KeyType id);
}
```

Now you can define

```
class PersonRepository : IRepository<int>
{
    public EntityType<int> Get(int id) { ... }
}
```

Obviously, you wouldn't be happy with that, because you would like to state that the Get method must return a `Person`, not just any `Entity<int>`.

The generic interface with two type parameters in the only solution. And indeed, there is a required relationship between them, as expressed in the constraint. But there is no redundancy here: specifying `int` for the type parameter doesn't carry enough information.

If we say

```
class PersonRepository : IRepository<int, Person>
{
    public Person Get(int id) { ... }
}
```

There is indeed redundancy: specifying the type parameter `int` is redundant when the type parameter `Person` has already been specified.

It would be possible to come op with a syntax that make it possible to infer the KeyType. For example, Patrick Hoffman suggested:

```
class PersonRepository : IRepository<EntityType: Person>. 
{
    public Person Get(int id) { ... }
}
```

While theoretically possible, I fear that this would add a lot of complexity to the language specification and the compiler, for very little gain. In fact, is there any gain at all? You certainly wouldn't be saving keystrokes! Compare these two:

```
// current syntax
class PersonRepository : IRepository<int, Person>
{
    public Person Get(int id) { ... }
}

// proposed syntax
class PersonRepository : IRepository<EntityType: Person>
{
    public Person Get(int id) { ... }
}
```

The language is what it is, and it doesn't look too bad to me.

Comment: `interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<int, Person>` Knowing that the first type parameter for `IRepository` is supposed to be the same for `Person` makes stating it explicitly in the declaration of `IPersonRepository` redundant, since it has been already declared: `class Person : Entity<int>`. The problem I have is to tell the compiler that they are indeed supposed to be the same, i.e. infer the type from the declaration of `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

No, C#'s type system is not sufficiently advanced to express what you want. The feature needed is called *higher kinded type* which are often found in strongly typed functional languages (Haskell, OCaml, Scala).

Working our way back, you want to be able to write

```
interface IRepository<EntityType<EntityKey>> {
  EntityType<EntityKey> Get(KeyType id);
}

interface PersonRepository : IRepository<Person> {
  Person Get(Int id);
}
```

but in C# there is no way to express the kind EntityType or, in other words, that the type parameter has some generic parameter and use that generic parameter in your code.

*Side note: The Repository pattern is Evil and must die in a fire.*

Comment: Wonderful answer. But why is the repository pattern evil? What alternatives would you suggest?

Comment: There is no usecase for a repository pattern. It works against you because generally they're a subinterface of the ORM you're using underneath that just forwards calls. It doesn't help with mocking and/or testing (you can't seriously mock where/get when you have to take in to account which expressions your database provider does and doesn't supply), it doesn't make your code more modular, it adds an extra layer of complexity, and in the rare case you are swapping out your ORM (yeah, right), you probably have to delve in to business logic anyway because of different performance charactersics.

Comment: As for alternatives, just use your ORM directly rather than wrapping it in a repository.

Comment: You have a point, but I still feel uncomfortable accessing the ORM implementation directly. True, most operations on a repository just forward calls to the ORM, but IMHO it still makes sense to shield business operations from the detais of accessing the infrastructure. Saying `UserRepository.ActiveUsers` is different (and much more clear) than something like `Session.CreateCriteria<User>().Add(Restrictions.Eq("_active", true)).List<User>()`. Any besides, doesn't the same performance argument apply to just accessing the database directly, not using ORM at all?

Comment: let me rephrase that :) A generic repository (`UserRepository.Save(User)`) doesn't do much. Isolating data access stuff like ActiveUsers from your business logic can make sense, especially if there is much data logic that isn't business logic in there. I would personally opt for extension methods on ISession for NHibernate or putting them directly in the DbContext for EF rather than wrapping them.

Answer (score -1):

No, that is not possible to write that, since it doesn't infer the type (the compiler doesn't).

It should be possible to do so (you need to be part of the C# compiler team though to get it in), since there is no other value possible that the value of `KeyType` put into the type parameter for `Entity`. You can't put in a derived type or a base class type.

As others commented though, it might over complicate your code. Also, this only works in the case that `Entity<T>` is a class, when it is an interface it can't infer the type since it can have multiple implementations. (Maybe that is the ultimate reason they didn't build this in)

Comment: `you need to be part of the C# compiler team though to get it in` - well, you could always fork Roslyn, if you don't mind no-one else being able to compile your code :)

Comment: @Rawling: I look forward to your implementation ;)

Comment: What exactly would the syntax look like? `interface IRepository<EntityType> where EntityType : Entity<KeyType>` is existing syntax with a well defined meaning. Of course, the compiler cannot compile that if the type `KeyType` does not exist. See also my answer.

Comment: Maybe `IRepository<EntityType: Person>`. That makes the `KeyType` 'optional'.

Comment: That might actually work. I fear it would add a lot of complexity to the language specification and the compiler though, for very little gain. I'd prefer the compiler team to spend their time on something more useful.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: True. That might be a reason for it's absence. I didn't say I would like to have it there, but technically it should be possible.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Agree. I have updated my answer to reflect this discussion.